# pdf creation issue in php mpdf

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am having issue with pdf creation code using mpdf with html and css data. 
Data content I am providing is not fully converts in pdf and its avoids some last contents.

These are some tickets in loop, So if 4 tickets, in pdf i was 3 tickets.
If 6 tickets, there was 4 tickets in pdf,

I tested the html content by saving the save variable value in mpdf to a txt file, and all tickets html code were there but not created in pdf.

Please suggest, Here is code of pdf creation I am using.

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',5,5,5,5,0,0);
$mpdf->use_kwt = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($designcontent);
$file = 'pdf/ticket'.$_POST['customerId'].'-'.date_format(date_create(),"Ymd_His").'.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($file);
```